# Mesh mixes up markers in multiple curves

Tags: mesh

Following is my code:

```
 ListLinePlot[{data11, data31, data51}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"■", "◆", "●"}, Mesh -> 10, GridLines -> Automatic,  
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, {0.75, 0.3}]]
```

Instead of showing markers circle and diamond, it is showing square overall.
[image: Manu]

Comment: `{data11, data31, data51}` have no definition

Comment: Try setting `Mesh->None` or delete this option altogether.

Comment: Try `{"□","◇","○"}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the plot markers and mesh markers are handled independently.

```
{data11, data31, data51} = Accumulate /@ ( RandomReal[#, 30] & /@ {1, {1, 2}, {2, 3}});

mesh = 10;
llp = ListLinePlot[{data11, data31, data51},  Mesh -> mesh,
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotMarkers -> Thread[{{"□", "◇",   "○"}, 16}], GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Right]]
```

[image]

One possible solution to place the plot markers at mesh points is to post-process the output to remove the plot markers and replace the mesh markers with corresponding plot markers. The function `fixMesh` below does that:

```
ClearAll[fixMesh]
fixMesh = Module[{meshcoords = Transpose[GatherBy[Cases[#, Point[x_] :> x, All], First]],
     insets = Cases[#, GeometricTransformation[i_, ___] :> i, All],
     styles = Cases[#, {d_, _GeometricTransformation} :> d, All], add},
    add = MapThread[{#, GeometricTransformation[#2, List/@#3]} &, 
     {styles, insets, meshcoords}];
    # /. {_Point -> Nothing, _GeometricTransformation -> add}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
fixMesh[llp]
```

[image]

With `mesh = 5;` we get

[image]

**Note:** This works for the default setting for `MeshFunctions` (which is `{#&}`).